# Decouple abstract class details from extended implementations

Tags: java, classloader, abstract-class, extends

I have a `PluginClassLoader` which is an abstract class that provides 99% of the functionality for my project's class loaders. I have 2 subclasses (`ServiceClassLoader`, and `ChannelClassLoader`) which extend `PluginClassLoader` and are little more than wrappers plus some customized logging. 99% of the logic is the same between the two implementations.

I then have a `PluginManager` which is also an abstract class which has 2 implementations that extend it (`ServiceManager` and `ChannelManager`) which are wrappers plus customized logging and a more convenient constructor.

The trouble I'm having is, in my `PluginManager` is must be able to instantiate a new class loader type, of either `ServiceClassLoader` or `ChannelClassLoader`. I'm trying to avoid having my `PluginManager` coupled to it's current implementations (ie. I want the flexibility of being able to add future implementations but not change `PluginManager`'s logic), so trying to avoid passing in some `Enum` and using some:

```
if (classLoaderType instanceof ClassLoaderType.SERVICE) {
    // do logic for instantiating ServiceClassLoader
}
```

Sample class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class PluginManager {
    // logic for managing plugins and when to load them
    // ...
    // somewhere deep in a loadPlugin(final File directory) method
    pluginLoader = new PluginClassLoader(); // <-- not valid, can't instantiate 
                                            //         an abstract class, 
                                            //         and it's of the wrong type!
}

public abstract class PluginClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    // class loader logic
}

public class ServiceManager extends PluginManager {
    // wrapper for PluginManager with some customized logging
}

public class ServiceClassLoader extends PluginClassLoader {
    // wrapper for PluginClassLoader with some customized logging
}
```

Trying to avoid doing something like:

```
public abstract class PluginManager {

    private final PluginType pluginType;

    public PluginManager(final PluginType pluginType) {
        this.pluginType = pluginType;
    }

    // logic ...

    // somewhere deep in the loadPlugin(final File directory) method
    if (pluginType instanceof PluginType.SERVICE) {
        pluginLoader = new ServiceClassLoader();
        // more logic
    } else if (plugintype instanceof PluginType.CHANNEL) {
        pluginLoader = new ChannelClassLoader();
        // more logic
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what is meant to determine the classloader to use. Should a ServiceManager always create a ServiceClassLoader, and some other PluginManager subclass always use a PluginClassLoader?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes exactly that. I'm trying to avoid overriding the `loadPlugin()` method for each manager since 99% of the details are identical, it's really only this line that would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an abstract method to `PluginManager` to make a class loader, and call it as needed. Subclasses should override that method, returning the appropriate subclass:

```
public abstract class PluginManager {
    public PluginManager() {
        pluginLoader = MakeClassLoader();
    }
    ...
    protected abstract PluginClassLoader MakeClassLoader();
}
public class ServiceManager extends PluginManager {
    ...
    protected abstract PluginClassLoader MakeClassLoader() {
        return new ServiceClassLoader();
    }
}
public class ChannelManager extends PluginManager {
    ...
    protected abstract PluginClassLoader MakeClassLoader() {
        return new ChannelClassLoader();
    }
}
```

This implements the [*Factory Method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing out on the amazing flexibility of `enum`s, they are fully blown objects in their own right and can therefore implement interfaces. If you make the enum itself capable of functioning as the factory all becomes simple.

Here's a greatly simplified demonstration of using an `enum` as a factory.

```
interface Loader {

    public Plugin load();
}

enum PluginType implements Loader {

    Service {

                @Override
                public Plugin load() {
                    return new ServiceClassLoader();
                }
            },
    Channel {

                @Override
                public Plugin load() {
                    return new ChannelClassLoader();
                }
            };
}

public void loadPlugin(PluginType type) {
    Plugin plugin = type.load();
}

public void test() {
    loadPlugin(PluginType.Channel);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Three options:

- Declare an abstract `newClassLoader()` method in `PluginManager`, which is overridden in `ServiceManager` to return a new `ServiceClassLoader` etc
- Change your parameter type from `PluginType` to `Class<? extends ClassLoader>`, store it in a field (e.g. `classLoaderClass`), and then just call `classLoader.newInstance()` when you need to
- Make `PluginType` an enum (if it's not already) which have its own method to create a new `ClassLoader`.

(It's not clear whether you need `PluginType` for other reasons - if you don't, then don't have it.)